# Android Studio Startup : Cannot Load Project - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, startup

I am relatively new to Android Studio (and to StackOverflow =D ) and recently started having problems with startup.

Whenever I launch Android Studio for the first time (i.e. after PC start / restart) all I get in the Android Studio project window is a dialog saying "**Cannot Load Project - java.lang.NullPointerException**".

When I click OK (no other option) there is nothing displayed in the project window. I got a red pop-up in the top right saying - **IDE Internal Error Occurred, click to view details**. Here is the error message I got from that:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateChecker.updateAndShowResult(UpdateChecker.kt:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.CheckForUpdateAction.actionPerformed(CheckForUpdateAction.java:40)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:312)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Got no idea what all this means... I am using the latest versions of the softwares on Windows 10 x64:

```
Android Studio 2.2.3
Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Wondering why this is happening and how I might resolve it? By the way, ***this only happens for the first time***, but I can't close it (unresponsive), so I have to End Task via Task Manager. When I start it again it does work fine, but gives the same error upon **next** PC start...

(I did a lot of searching about this on the internet but couldn't find any reference to such a problem except that people had older outdated versions of software - but I am running latest stable versions of all softwares - which is why I couldn't find anything)

Any help would be appreciated =)

Comment: By 'it' I mean Android Studio - I cannot Exit it via File, and the same error occurs with every project I try to open via File>Open/Open Recent...

Comment: Recommendation try to build a new hello world project and see if it happens for another project. After that try to copy all your files from the old project to the new "hello world" project.

Comment: I tried that @AndreiT but it seems to be for all projects

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too after an update and windows restart. 
Not sure, but it could be due to a bug in the recent version of Android Studio.

The temporary solution that works for me is to kill ("end process") the Android Studio executable (studio64.exe) from Task Manager, and run it again.

Once it starts working well, update to the latest version.